# Which digest algorithm is used when generating signed apk in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

Which digest algorithm is used when generating signed apk in Android Studio? How can i change it to other algorithm, like SHA1? Thanks.

Comment: For that purposes you want change signing algorithm to another?

Answer (score 1):

For changing singing algorithm you can use `jarsigner` binary located in `jdk` package.

Something like this:

`jarsigner -keystore mykeystore -storepass password -sigalg SHA256withRSA -digestalg SHA1 my.apk test`

or

`jarsigner -keystore mykeystore -storepass password -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA256 my.apk test`

Use this link [jarsigner docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html) to read what algorithms can be used for.

Comment: Read the question property before answering. Question is, Which algorithm (may be, by default) is used by android studio while generating signed APK.  Not which algorithms can be used (out of android studio, as you described).

Comment: @Mazhar thank you for answer!
But as you can see one of question is: `How can i change it to other algorithm, like SHA1?`
I think, that my answer describe some technics for do it.

Comment: it would be great if you show, how to change it with-in android studio. Thanks